# Restore SQL Server database backup of one machine to another

Tags: sql-server, database, database-restore

Scenario:

- I have a database backup (`abc.bak`) on one machine
- I copied it to another machine to some path let's say `G:\SQLDB\backup\master_copy.bak`
- I used the following T-SQL to try and restore - but I get errors.

T-SQL used:

```
RESTORE DATABASE New_DB
FROM DISK = 'G:\SQLDB\backup\master_copy.bak' 
WITH 
    MOVE 'coop_test_dat' TO 'G:\SQLDB\livedb\new_db_data.mdf',
    MOVE 'coop_test_log' TO 'G:\SQLDB\livedb\new_db_log.ldf',
    REPLACE
```

Error generated:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\SQLDB\masterdb\master_blank.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   File 'coop_demo' cannot be restored to 'C:\SQLDB\masterdb\master_blank.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Here given specified path is from old machine which doesn't exists in new machine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error message is about the file `coop_demo`. You're only moving the files `coop_test_dat` and `coop_test_log`. (In general, your error message doesn't seem to match your scenario at all, but that may be due to improper replacing on your end. Try sticking to *one* exact scenario, preferrably not hypothetical.)  Try [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql) to get full information on the files contained in the backup and the proper `MOVE` clauses.

Comment: coop_demo is name of old db in my old machine... i need to restore it to new db name : new_db in new location in new machine

Comment: `coop_demo` is *also* the name of a file of the database. Why? Because the error message says so.

Comment: coop_demo is logical file name of old db in old machine, do i need to use that name instead of coop_test_dat

Comment: Why are you even asking me instead of trying it? The answer is an unqualified YES. `RESTORE` uses logical names, as [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) will straight up tell you.

Comment: thanks for pointing mistake,,,, got it working....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what Jeroen suggested was, you might be missing some files..so to see all files  use below command..

```
restore filelistonly from disk ='your .bak path' with file=1
```

The output of above command will show you all the files that were backed up,then you can use restore with replace

so if restore  file list showed below as logical file names

```
logicalname  
db_Data
db_Data1
db_log
```

now you can use

```
RESTORE DATABASE New_DB
FROM DISK = 'G:\SQLDB\backup\master_copy.bak' WITH 
MOVE 'db_Data' TO 'G:\SQLDB\livedb\new_db_data.mdf',
MOVE 'db_Data1' TO 'G:\SQLDB\livedb\new_db_data1.ndf',
MOVE 'db_lof TO 'G:\SQLDB\livedb\new_db_log.log',
REPLACE
```